# Finding the missing side of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Quadrilateral $ABCD$ is circumscribed about circle $O$. If $AB=52$, $BC = 40$, and $AD =48$. How can I find the length of $CD$? I know the answer should be $36$, but I am unsure of how to arrive at that answer.[image]

Comment: Prove that $AB+CD=BC+AD$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label the tangent points as shown:

[image]

Clearly $AE=AH, BE=BF, CF=CG, DG=DH$

Then
$\begin{align}
CD &=CG+DG \\
 &= CF+DH\\
 &= (BC-BF)+(AD-AH)\\
 &= BC + AD - (BF+AH)\\
 &= BC + AD - (BE+AE)\\
 &= BC + AD - AB\
\end{align}$

(Perhaps more compactly, $AD+BC = AB+CD$ is almost immediately obvious)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For each vertex, the two segments connecting that vertex to a point of tangency in the circle are the same length. (Why?)

So, for instance, if the points of tangency are $P \in \overline{AB}$, $Q \in \overline{BC}$, $R \in \overline{CD}$ and $S \in \overline{AD}$, then $\overline{AP}$ and $\overline{AS}$ have the same length.